# How to create a generic list to store data of any type

Tags: java

I'm creating simple column-oriented database for learning purpose. Based on the type of the attribute, i want to create a list of the same type and set data in it.

```
public class Relation {
    private Table table;
    private Integer id;
    private Map<String, List<?>> columns; // is this correct?

    public Relation(Table table) {
        this.table = table;
        this.id = 1;
        this.columns = new HashMap<>();

        for (Attribute attribute: table.getAttributes()) {
            if (attribute.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("String")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                columns.put(attribute.getName(), list);
            }

            if (attribute.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Integer")) {
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                columns.put(attribute.getName(), list);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setIntegerData(String colName, Integer val) {
        this.columns.get(colName).add(val); // how to set this?
    }

    public void setStringData(String colName, String val) {
        this.columns.get(colName).add(val);
    }
}
```

I'm getting following error

```
/Users/pranay.sankpal/inmemsql/src/main/java/com/inmemsql/engine/Relation.java:32:34
java: no suitable method found for add(java.lang.Integer)
    method java.util.Collection.add(capture#1 of ?) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to capture#1 of ?)
    method java.util.List.add(capture#1 of ?) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to capture#1 of ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make the value of the map a list of objects.

```
public class Relation {
 
    private Integer id;
    private Map<String, List> columns; 

    public Relation(){
        columns = new HashMap<>();
        columns.put("key1", new ArrayList());
        columns.put("key2", new ArrayList());
    }
    
    public void setData(String colName, Object val) {
        this.columns.get(colName).add(val); 
    }

}
```